# Using a bitwise & inside an if statement

Tags: java, c, if-statement, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

In C, I can write an if-statement

```
if (firstInt & 1)
```

but when I try and do the same in Java, the compiler tells me "incompatible types" and says I need a `boolean` instead of an `int`. Is there any way to write that C code in Java?

Comment: The reason this works in C/C++ is that the languages interpret expressions inside conditionals by implicitly comparing their results to zero. Java is very strict in this regard, requiring a boolean expression in the conditionals.

Comment: It's not just implicit; C doesn't even _have_ a boolean type.

Comment: @Taymon C has the boolean type `_Bool` and the macro `bool` in `stdbool.h` which expands to `_Bool`

Comment: @Taymon: C still has the concept of a *boolean expression* which is what is being referred to here - *not* the type `bool`.

Comment: @ouah: Not in C89 it does not.  Granted most compilers now support at least C99, but _Bool and stdbool.h is still a fairly recent addition to Microsoft's compiler for example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any of the following should work for you:

```
if ((firstInt & 1) != 0)
if ((firstInt & 1) > 0)
if ((firstInt & 1) == 1)
```

Comment: Please note that the parens (which I've added) are necessary for correctness. In Java, comparison operators bind more tightly than binary bitwise operators.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: I would argue that this form is good practice in C and C++ also.

Answer (score 1):

In C an integer expression can be used implicitly as a boolean expression (although I would argue that it is a bad idea), where zero is false and any non-zero value is true.

In Java that is not allowed so you have to make the expression explicitly boolean by comparing the integer result to some other integer value or expression using a comparison operator.