# Java equivalent of if (edgeTable[cubeindex] & 256) in c++

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a bitwise & inside an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064068/using-a-bitwise-inside-an-if-statement)

I have the following piece of code from http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polygonise/

```
    if (edgeTable[cubeindex] & 1)
      vertlist[0] =
         VertexInterp(isolevel,grid.p[0],grid.p[1],grid.val[0],grid.val[1]);
   if (edgeTable[cubeindex] & 2)
      vertlist[1] =
         VertexInterp(isolevel,grid.p[1],grid.p[2],grid.val[1],grid.val[2]);
```

How can i rewrite the if statements so they will run in Java ?

Regards Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edgeTable[cubeindex] & 1` is a valid operation in Java and has the same meaning as in C. You can have a look at the [Java tutorial on Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for more information.

But you need to test for an explicit condition in the if statement:

```
if ((edgeTable[cubeindex] & 1) != 0)
```

Comment: Case of requiring an explicit boolean expression result: `if ((edgeTable[cubeindex] & 1) != 0)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Absolutely, edited.